# Error after adding project dependency

Tags: gradle

I use Gradle to build multiple projects laid out like this:

```
ares/build.gradle
ares/settings.gradle
ares/ares-gui/build.gradle
ares/ares-persistence/build.gradle
ares/ares-entities/build.gradle
ares/ares-persistence-config/build.gradle
```

All projects have either java or scala gradle plugins applied.

In project `ares-gui` I added two project dependencies:

```groovy
dependencies {
    ...
    myConfiguration project(':ares-entities')
    myConfiguration project(':ares-persistence')
    ...
}
```

When I run `gradle eclipse`, I get this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ares-gui'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ares-gui:runtime'.
   > Module version group:ares, module:ares-gui, version:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT, configuration:runtime declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ares, module:ares-persistence, version:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
```

The interesting thing is that when I leave only one dependency (to `ares-entities`), everything is fine.

Any idea why this happens?

EDIT: This is actually very interesting: when I changed the name of `ares-persistence` to `ares-bpersistence` (lexicographically before `ares-gui`), the problem went away! A bug?

EDIT2: Here's some more info about the problem:

Gradle version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.0-milestone-9
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: wtorek, 13 marzec 2012 16:10:09 UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_26 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.1-b02)
OS: Linux 2.6.38-13-generic amd64
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':ares-gui'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:462)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$1.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:438)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:433)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
    at org.gradle.messaging.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ares-gui:runtime'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$BrokenResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:458)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection$1.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:88)
    at build_12d77nfltt9q8t8qb7c0m6lmai$_run_closure4_closure7.doCall(/home/ghik/iosr/ares/ares-gui/build.gradle:45)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:141)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.osgi.OsgiPluginConvention.osgiManifest(OsgiPluginConvention.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.groovy:73)
    at build_12d77nfltt9q8t8qb7c0m6lmai$_run_closure4.doCall(/home/ghik/iosr/ares/ares-gui/build.gradle:39)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:141)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:392)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:57)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:133)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$ContainerElementsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:315)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.groovy:73)
    at build_12d77nfltt9q8t8qb7c0m6lmai.run(/home/ghik/iosr/ares/ares-gui/build.gradle:38)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Module version group:ares, module:ares-gui, version:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT, configuration:runtime declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ares, module:ares-persistence-config, version:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:322)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:283)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:236)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:456)
    ... 78 more
```

It also turns out that the problem disappears when I remove one line from the build script:

```groovy
war {
    manifest = osgiManifest {
        ...
        // this line is causing problems
        def someLibs = classpath.files.collect{ 'WEB-INF/lib/'+it.name }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an evaluation order problem. Without knowing the Gradle version, build scripts, and stack trace, I can't tell what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I added some more information. Sorry for not thinking about it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classpath.files` in the code above resolves a file collection at build configuration time. This should be avoided whenever possible. For one thing, it means that the file collection will get resolved for each and every build (possibly involving downloads), no matter which task on which project gets executed. In this particular case, it also causes the project dependency on `:ares-persistence` to get resolved, which fails because that project's build script hasn't been evaluated yet.

The solution is to make sure that the file collection only gets resolved at execution time. How this is done depends on the exact circumstances of what you are trying to achieve. Common solutions are to use lazy Gradle APIs, do the work in a callback registered with one of the many hooks that Gradle provides, or do the work in a `doFirst {}` block.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the whole manifest configuration into a `doFirst` and it works.