# Cant build Gradle for LeakCanary library

Tags: android, gradle, leakcanary

I tried to build Gradle:

> Executing command: "--stacktrace"
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Build file 'H:\Nin_in_the_winD\working.space\development\branch\eazy\build.gradle' line: 2
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'eazy'.
>
>   > Could not find method debugCompile() for arguments [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1@aar] on root project 'eazy'.
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'eazy'.
>     at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
>     at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
>     at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
>     at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method debugCompile() for arguments [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1@aar] on root project 'eazy'.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:175)
>     at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
>     at build_4cypqr1onvufm2h2phqvhowz7$_run_closure1.doCall(H:\Nin_in_the_winD\working.space\development\branch\eazy\build.gradle:2)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
>     at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
>     at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:91)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.dependencies(AbstractProject.java:838)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:232)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:127)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
>     at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
>     at build_4cypqr1onvufm2h2phqvhowz7.run(H:\Nin_in_the_winD\working.space\development\branch\eazy\build.gradle:1)
>     at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
>     ... 35 more

Here is my gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1@aar'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1@aar'
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nin I think that you need 'compile' default line, add this line in your dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Say me if you can repair your error!! Good luck!

Comment: Now it show me:
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on root project 'eazy'.

Comment: Delete latest compile line and tries this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9960857/3996257
Says me something and good luck!